# Trying to select a value from a field based on the value of a date field, where the first value is not NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a huge table of past records that looks similar to this:

```
field1,    field2,   field3,   startDate, lastUpdate
--------------------------------------------------
 1         A        B       NULL       3/1/2014
 1         A        B       1/5/2014   3/2/2014
 1         A        B       1/7/2014   3/3/2014
 1         A        B       1/2/2014   3/4/2014 
 1         A        B       NULL       3/5/2014
 2         C        D       1/28/2014  3/1/2014
 2         C        D       1/17/2014  3/2/2014
 2         C        D       NULL       3/3/2014
 2         C        D       NULL       3/4/2014 
 2         C        D       NULL       3/5/2014
```

I am trying to write a query where I could turn field1, field2, and field3 into one distinct record and then have the `startDate` value be based on the most current `lastUpdate` value where `startDate is not NULL`. So my ideal output for this would look like this:

```
field1,   field2,    field3, startDate 
--------------------------------------

 1        A         B     1/2/2014
 2        C         D     1/17/2014
```

My SQL skills are not that strong, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
; WITH CTE
AS 
(
   SELECT field1, field2, field3, startDate, lastUpdate,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY field1, field2, field3 
                          ORDER BY lastUpdate DESC) AS RN
   FROM Table_Name 
   WHERE startDate IS NOT NULL
) 
SELECT  field1, field2, field3, startDate, lastUpdate
FROM CTE 
WHERE RN = 1
```

Comment: I was writing the same query, after the refresh I refrain and spell checked your :)

Comment: To the OP: Row_Number() is a SQLServer 2005 or better functionality

Answer (score 0):

You can do a self-join to find the largest `lastUpdated`

```
select field1, field2, field3, startDate
from table t1
where startDate is not null
  and not exists (select * from table t2 
                  where t1.field1=t2.field1 
                    and t1.field2=t2.field2 
                    and t1.field3=t2.field3
                    and startDate is not null
                    and t1.lastUpdate<t2.lastUpdate)
```

This will filter all rows that have a `null` startDate, and for each set, it will ignore all the rows that have a row with the same conditions and a larger lastUpdate value.

Working [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/68d82/2)